# Parsing static json file and save values to Django Database/model

Tags: json, django, django-models, django-views

I have json file in my static folder in my django project. And I want to save the data from json file to my Django Database.

This is my model.py

```py
from django.db import models


class Coming_Soon(models.Model):
    movie_id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=11)
    movie_title = models.TextField(blank=True, max_length=100)
    image_url = models.TextField(blank=True)
    synopsis = models.TextField(blank=True)
    rating = models.TextField(default="MTRCB rating not yet available")
    cast = models.TextField(blank=True)
    release_date = models.TextField()
```

this is sample of my json file

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "rating": "PG",
      "cast": [
        "Jeremy Ray Taylor",
        "Gerard Butler",
        "Abbie Cornish"
      ],
      "synopsis": "some synopsis",
      "movie_title": "(3D/4DX) GEOSTORM",
      "image_url": "some url",
      "id": "8595"
    },
    {
      "rating": "PG",
      "cast": [
        "Jeremy Ray Taylor",
        "Gerard Butler",
        "Abbie Cornish"
      ],
      "synopsis": "some synopsis",
      "movie_title": "(ATMOS) GEOSTORM",
      "image_url": "some url",
      "id": "8604"
    }
  ]
}
```

what should I write on my view so that I can save those data into my django database? This is my views.py:

```py
def polls(request):
    ROOT_FILE = STATIC_ROOT + '/polls/coming_soon.json'
    json_data = open(ROOT_FILE)
    json_load = json.load(json_data)

    with open(ROOT_FILE, 'r') as data:
        parsed_json = json.load(data)

        for result in parsed_json['results']:
    # HOW CAN I SAVE DATA INTO DATABASE??
```

I really don't have any idea about getting those file into my database. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can create obj like this

```
from .models import Coming_Soon
   def polls(request):

    ROOT_FILE = STATIC_ROOT + '/polls/coming_soon.json'
    json_data = open(ROOT_FILE)
    json_load = json.load(json_data)

    with open(ROOT_FILE, 'r') as data:
    parsed_json = json.load(data)

    for result in parsed_json['results']:
        Coming_Soon.objects.create(
           movie_id = result['id'],
           movie_title = result['movie_title'],
           image_url=result['image_url'],
           synopsis = result['synopsis'], 
         )
```

Comment: how about to save the CAST key with multiple values?? when i tried this the data in database is a list like this [ "Jeremy Ray Taylor",  "Gerard Butler", "Abbie Cornish"], not a string like this Jeremy Ray Taylor,  Gerard Butler, Abbie Cornish ? Thank you

Comment: cast=result['cast']

Comment: yes man, but what it saves to the database is in list format not in string format.

Comment: you are using a TextField for cast

Comment: arrayfield - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#arrayfield

Comment: if you are using postgres use a ArrayField

Comment: I already solved my problem, I use the join() method to separate them. Thank you man for the help.

Comment: then  just convert it into a JSON string, and then save that as Text in the model. You can then retrieve the list by converting the (JSON) string back into a python list

Comment: hi sachim, I hope you can help me with my another problem. this is my problem now. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57240043/django-data-to-jsonresponse